# How to add Dynamic Partition Hive table with Calculated Column

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, partitioning

I create a external hive table and it's source is HDFS file. I need add a dynamic partition which has some calculated thing like "to_date(from_unixtime(cast(unix_time_stamp/1000 as INT)))" .

however when i execute the script that shared below, i faced an error like :

`Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 13:33 cannot recognize input near '(' 'cast' '(' in column type`

Script :

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;

set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name 
(
`ww_cnt` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
`s_t_cnt` bigint COMMENT 'from deserializer',
`po_cnt` array<struct<name:string,
count:bigint>> COMMENT 'from deserializer',
`unix_time_stamp` bigint COMMENT 'from deserializer'
)

**PARTITIONED BY (to_date(from_unixtime(cast(unix_time_stamp/1000 as INT))))** 

ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'

STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'

OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'

LOCATION
'hdfs_file_path'
```

Comment: I don't think you can run functions while partitioning, but you'd want `cast((unix_time_stamp/1000) as INT)` and you don't need parenthesis around `to_date()`

Comment: partition by should be a column like `unix_time_stamp timestamp` and you shouldnt put any calculation like this. when inserting or loading you can use this logic.

Comment: hi @KoushikRoy, i am change my approach for problem. however, you r right, i shouldnt put any calculation column for partition. thanks for your answer.